# can azure durable functions support, cancel, suspend and retry/replay activites?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

we are exploring azure durable functions to facilitate the following requirements, can the durable functions support these ?

1. a user can suspend the workflow and resume when he wants
2. if an activity of workflow fails, the user can retry that particular activity with human intervention as many number of time he wants
3. a user can choose from which step the workflow can be resumed, to be more brief if 2 of the 4 steps have been executed in the workflow the user can re-run the workflow from the beginning (Step 1)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to "stop" the execution using External Event to stop the processing of an execution. You can restart the execution using Rewind API, but it will restart the whole workflow, not particular tasks.

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-instance-management?tabs=csharp#rewind-instances-preview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp